# Why does CUDA CUdeviceptr use unsigned int instead of void?

Tags: cuda

Just curious.

Why does functions in driver API use unsigned int as CUdeviceptr, instead of void?

Runtime API use void, though.

Comment: is it so? In 64-bit it is unsigned long long since Cuda 3.2 (see line 147 in cuda.h from version 5.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the underlying reason is because a CUdeviceptr is a *handle* to an allocation in device memory and not an address in device memory. The driver looks up addresses internally from a memory map using this handle, and the internal driver API requires it to be an unsigned integer.

Tim Murray, who was at one stage in charge of CUDA driver development at NVIDIA, wrote [this answer](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/467742/cudeviceptr-should-be-typdedef-39-d-as-void-instead-of-unsigned-int/) on another forum a few years ago. I think that is about as authoritative answer as you will find (although Nick Wilt, who was the original CUDA driver author, also answers questions here on Stack Overflow occasionally and might chime in and provide a better answer than mine).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer :)

Comment: They always have been pointers in the CUDA address space; originally it was because the pointer sizes were different for the GPUs and CPUs (SM 1.x GPUs do not support 64-bit addresses); and there was a desire to enforce some type safety between host and device pointers.  But on 64-bit platforms, you can cast directly between the two by using uintptr_t as an intermediary.